# Redifine \aisize in authorindex package for footnotesize

Tags: fontsize, renewcommand, authorindex

I'm using the authorindex package to make a, you guessed it, index of authors.

I'd like to make the fontsize smaller than the built-in command \aisize allows; it has normal (default) and small, but my publisher requires footnotesize.

The package doc says "You can redefine it outside the theauthorindex environment to customize the font size". Has anyone done this? I have very little experience with redefining commands...

Answer (score 1):

the `small` option just does

```
\renewcommand\aisize{\small}
```

so you want

```
\renewcommand\aisize{\footnotesize}
```

after loading the package

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want to try and figure these kind of things out, do I look in the .sty file to try and see what the commands do?